# Google CloudSQL - How to remove the default postgres user?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

When I create a new database instance in Google CloudSQL, it creates a default user called postgres. I created another user and when I tried to remove the default postgres user I received a message: Can not remove a System user.

Some months ago I could remove the default user without problems. Did google change anything in CloudSQL? How can I remove the default user?

Answer (score 0):

The postgres user is part of the cloudsqlsuperuser role. Because Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL is a managed service, it restricts access to certain system procedures and tables that require advanced privileges. In Cloud SQL, customers cannot create or have access to users with superuser attributes, including the postgres user. This is documented on the [PostgreSQL users](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users#default-users) documentation page.